# Sharepoint powershell to associate a site template

Tags: sharepoint, templates, powershell, migration

During database detach and attach process, all the sites are migrated to the new 2010 farm but are not yet associated with any site template. I want to be able to run through all the sites that do not have any site template associated yet and are just sitting there in the content DB and then be able to assign them a site template like a team site.

Is it possible to accomplish this using powershell in sharepoint?
Someone please give me their insights here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through site collections if you access `SPFarm.Local.Services`. Then you have to look for web application objects and in each of them you can look for sites.

In c# code you can do it like this:

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
foreach (SPService objService in farm.Services) {
   if (objService is SPWebService) {
       SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)objService;
       foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications) {
          foreach (SPSite site in webApp.Sites) {
             foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs) {
                 if (web.Provisioned == false) {
                   //...whatever
                 }
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```